# Typescript - type guard not narrowing a union with generic types and functions

Tags: typescript

I have two nominally-typed functions using the following method (put aside why I'd do it this way--this example is simplified to try to make my question clear):

```
interface OneArgFunc<T> { 
 label: "oneArgFunc"
 innerFunc:(x: string, y:T)=>void
}
interface TwoArgFunc<T> {
 label: "twoArgFunc"
 innerFunc: (a:number, b:string, c:T)=>void
}
```

I also have a union of the two and type guards for distinguishing:

```
type UnionFunc<V> = OneArgFunc<V> | TwoArgFunc<V>

// Type guard functions
function isOneArgFunc<V>(func: UnionFunc<V>): func is OneArgFunc<V> {
    return func.label === "oneArgFunc"
}
function isTwoArgFunc<V>(func: UnionFunc<V>): func is TwoArgFunc<V> {
    return func.label === "twoArgFunc"
}
```

But if I call one of the type guards on the union it does not narrow the remainder (the "else" statement) to the other half of the union:

```
function transfomer<U extends UnionFunc<any>>(func:U){
    if(isOneArgFunc(func)) {
       return (g:any)=>func.innerFunc("test", g)
    }
    else {
        return (g:any)=>func.innerFunc(1, "test", g)
        //                             ^ -- error here
        // TS indicates that narrowed type of innerFunc is
        // (property) innerFunc: (arg0: never, arg1: any, c: any) => void
        //  What is that based on?
    }
}
```

If I explicitly call the second type guard in the else statement, it works as expected:

```
function transfomerTwo<U extends UnionFunc<any>>(func:U){
    if(isOneArgFunc(func)) {
       return (y:any)=>func.innerFunc("test", y)
    }
    else if(isTwoArgFunc(func)) {
        return (z:any)=>func.innerFunc(1, "test", z)
    }
    else {return func}
}
```

But I can't figure out why the first one above doesn't work?  I'm assuming the union is not really binary for some reason, but I can't exactly see how or how TS comes up with the bizarre function signature for innerFunc after the else statement.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Full code is on [this playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIggQSgcwGICuICAPACoB8yA3sgFDKPIA2cARhMwFzIBEA9hmz4iCXgyagMUQsS4AKAB48AzmCigcAGmQBPLmQCUAXgoA3fsAAmdAL51QkWIhRkA7v2GzSlGg1Yc3HxgHl6i4shS0N488nBcIAQAthxQOmxcahog2sgIBibmljb2YLoADigAqiDAgt4kAGpUxmhCuA3NyAA+yO6eHaJNFHR0APRjfRUoOARwUFbIMKJgdSAqdMvEq4KRKuhYg8TD8lv5yDVrnRSGPGd7bYcix13UEoxQEGAEUCBLogA6AKcZDGMF8QRPbziexnHZ-YAqfphF4UU6iHiXepDZq3f7EB7Io6kV7vZCfb6-fEIIHsEFg1q8EIDZ5iOyjCZ9AAWiOp8OQVn4EBUyBA-DAovmUH4bmQYC5KF4nBUEF4eTgKrl-D6oWJmxWazlUDg6xg-CS0BIVWQEEUkBAVhFWJADRNugoaLOXCqhjeTEiMHkiIOKIQ6OIhkMfn9TApPz+8hwXDdhTOAKiMlE8iZwrAvB0OEMZPs-uVKD9MY+X3jyETyZAulTgIz3nkAEYdDm1PnkIWyf7OZWh8OhwA9ZAAWgnNqg0qgyAVn37TE5ZAAypEHcAEHBICL5bvJbOZRBFmVKsh+DBN9JvHtl4xOfJytLKlAylGWxja-McAAGHgMDMaAdF-NseDdHRzhTUEqAsawH2QQcAHUuUPXkDwlNgNVPS8QAAfmLdlxkmMgeRFSFkA8KAAGsRQ1G1FEqBBIBsOFDXUE0VDNC0oH6K1GPtR0LlqbFjjdD1w3yH0K0YYBA2DdpWSkyNo0rOMqXkfQU1MNMv2IbM9zzHRGyI0tmE1eSgyRXVlLOVTZJjDSEwAL3rRtdObEBbyzDtglzHsXKLf0SyYMsaGc6l7HsOggA)

Answer (score 1):

Would the following work for you ? I think it is better to specify the generic type to isOneArgFunc. At least it does not raise any error anymore.

```
function transfomer<T>(func:UnionFunc<T>){
    if(isOneArgFunc<T>(func)) {
       return (g:any)=>func.innerFunc("test", g)
    }
    else {
        return (g:any)=>func.innerFunc(1, "test", g)
        //                             ^ -- No more error
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as expected.  Any idea why this works and the way I had it does not?  It seems like something about the use of "any" in the type parameter constraint causes the weird bisection of the union, but I can't figure out what.  In any event, that you for picking this up.  If no one has more of an explanation, I will mark this answer as accepted.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I am no expert @sam256 but I guess it has to do with the fact that isOneArgFunc is a generic function and you are not explicitly putting the type to that function in your solution.